# Proof of the result below without the primitive element theorem?

Tags: abstract-algebra

If $K(a,b)$ is a extension field of the field $K$, where $a$, $b$ are algebraic over $K$ and $b$ is separable. We know that if $K$ is infinite, we can find $u$ of $K$ such that
$K(a,b)=K(a+bu)$, so there are only a finite number of intermediate fields between $K$ and $K(a,b)$.

Can you give a proof of this result (there are only a finite number of intermediate fields between $K$ and $K(a,b)$) without the primitive element theorem?

Comment: What happens if $K$ is infinite and $b$ is separable but $a$ is not separable?